# In region public games, is there chatting?

Tags: simcity-2013

I can't find this anywhere and I haven't been able to get past the server issues. If you join a public game in say a region that has 4 other players building cities, can you chat with those players in game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can open region chat simply by pressing **"Enter"**

This will send a message to everyone playing in your region. If you wish to have individual conversations, it is best to add the player as a friend on Origin.

Comment: Or use the button in the upper left corner.